# Selenium - Update to WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am using "selenium-server-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar" jar file to run my test suite in selenium test runner. It runs well in firefox & chrome, but it gives this info text in the test run report

"info: Selenium 1.0 (Core, RC, etc) is no longer under active development. Please update to WebDriver ASAP"

How do i update to webdriver manually? or How can i get rid of this info text?

Comment: Check whether you have downloaded the correct version. And did you use RC before?

Comment: Hi Vignesh, Yes I have the correct version. I am new to RC.

Comment: 2.44 is a webdriver version, you need to understand the basic of selenium and look at it, pretty easy to grab.

Comment: yes that is why i am confused as to why it would say i need to upgrade to webdriver as its supposed to be the webdriver version. I am trying to find out where is it getting that info text which sees 2.44.0 version as 1.0 I do understand the selenium concept just that before the actual scripting in C# i want to make sure that i can actually run it in all browsers, using the basic cmd "testRunner" prompt.

Comment: How are you running your tests? Give us an example of one of your tests.

Comment: Hi Arran, i run "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -htmlsuite *firefox URL "c:\selenium-server\OnlineReportSuite.html" "c:\selenium-server\TestResultsFirefoxOnline.html" on command prompt.

Comment: Hi, i'm getting same error. I'm using Selenium IDE, I run this from command prompt: java -jar C:\Apps\SeleniumTest\selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.google.com" "C:\Apps\SeleniumTest\SeleniumSuite.html" "C:\Apps\SeleniumTest\SeleniumTestResult.html". Can somebody tell me why am i getting this error because i have not used webdriver or RC before. The test suite executes successfully but the message appears in info.

Answer (score 1):

The info message you are seeing is essentially warning you that if you continue to use the Selenium RC API, your tests can stop working with more recent releases of browsers. In the upcoming Selenium 3, the RC API will be dropped outright.

There is no way to just get rid of the text, it is a warning message, and it is a valuable warning message.

In order to move on to WebDriver you will need to rewrite all your tests. A suggestion is to start with failing ones first. Start by reading through the official [documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp). There is also a [link](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_migrating_from_rc_to_webdriver.jsp#migrating-to-webdriver-reference) from there pointing you towards more specifics. While you are at it, you might also want to consider refactoring your code to use [PageObjects](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects), which was not available in Selenium 1.

Note that while you are migrating your tests, it is quite possible to run a mix of WebDriver and RC tests in the same project.

Answer (score -3):

Point is WebDriver is half finished kind of thing and people not that deeply testing websites, it was useful to have IDE and automate quickly, so this selenium 1.0 works much better and should not be disabled at any point.